# onclick on the ul list in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular

I have a list and I want to fetch the class name on click any of the li

```
<ul id='color' name='color' class="choose-color" (click)=getColor()>
              <li class="color1"></li>
              <li class="color2"></li>
              <li class="color3"></li>
            </ul>
```

i have tried 3 different solution but not a single one is working

// #### solution 1

```
 $('#color > li').click(function() { 
           alert(this.class);
            console.log("doce");
 });
```

// #### solution 2

```
 $('.color > li').click(function() { 
           alert(this.class);
            console.log("docevdfvd");
 });
```

// #### solution 3

```
  $('ul > li').click(function() { 
           //  $('#selectedList').show();
           alert(this.class);
            console.log("docevdfvdwcwecwecfe");
 });
```

so can you help me ..how can we achive this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns aren't dynamic :

```
<ul id='colorList' name='colorList' class="choose-color">
    <li class="workspace-fill-color{{i}}" *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]" (click)="getColor(i)"></li>
</ul>
```

In your component :

```
getColor(i) {
    let class = $(`.workspace-fill-color${i}`).attr('class');
    // Or simply 
    let class = `workspace-fill-color${i}`;
}
```